# Buffer overflow in async js' eachSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to crawl a directory. I think I'm hitting an overflow using async js' eachSeries because I keep adding items to the array in my breadth-first search function.

Is there anything I can use that pops / dequeue an array in async manner until it's empty? Or is there a workaround to this issue I'm having?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created my own function e.g.

```
var async2 = {
  popEachSeries: function(stack, callback, callbackFinished) {
    if (stack && stack.length > 0) {
      var item = stack.pop();
      callback(item, function() {
        async2.popEachSeries(stack, callback, callbackFinished);
      });
    } else {
      if (callbackFinished) {
        callbackFinished();
      }
    }
  }
}
```